# Make AJAX call only once with multiple dependency loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Whenever I click on the button which makes AJAX call to other page which contains a JS file named `status.js`, It loads everytime when an AJAX call is made.

I need it to load only once or else if loaded multiple times then it should execute only one.

Comment: I recommend including "status.js" in the first page (note the ajax-loaded page) if at all possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see you doing this 2 ways:

1. Wrap your code inside "status.js" in a variable.

   ```
   if (!status || status === undefined) {
       var status = function() {
           // code here
       }
   }
   ```
2. OR instead of ajax use the jQuery load function and load just the body of the page you need (https://api.jquery.com/load/):

   ```
   $( "#result" ).load( "ajax/test.html #container" );
   ```

   With this, you could for example build a switch inside and on first button click, load the entire page, but on second click load everything but the scripts

   ```
   firstClick = true;

   if(firstClick) {
       // load entire page
       firstClick = false;
   } else {
       // load everything but the scripts
   }
   ```